# RestTemplate post value can not pass

Tags: java

With restTemplate call interface, the interface can not accept the data, the code is as follows`

```
    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    map.put("name", "xiaohong");

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpEntity<Map<String,Object>> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<Map<String,Object>>(map,headers);

    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> coverterList = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    coverterList.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    coverterList.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
    coverterList.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());


    String url = "http://127.0.0.1:8099/test/tput/xiaoming";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(coverterList);
    ResponseEntity<Object> result = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, httpEntity, Object.class);








@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/tput/{age}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Object testput(HttpServletRequest request,@PathVariable("age") String age){

    // name is null
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    System.out.println(name);


    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    map.put("name", name);
    map.put("age", age);
    return map;
```

`
Can not get the value of "name"
Print the result :  null

Comment: Do you want to get the value of name field on `    System.out.println(result.getBody());` ?

Comment: want to get name form method "testput" ,but  name is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the question goes I think you are trying to fetch the value of "name" field from the Response of Post Request. To do such you can create a new Object and Cast the value from the Response and fetch the data accordingly like,

**User.java**

```
public class User
{
    private String age;
    private String name;
    public User()
    {
    }
    public User(String age, String name)
    {
        this.user = age;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(String age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And, Then on RestTemplate Post Method Execution you can use `postForObject`,

```
User result = restTemplate.postForObject(url, httpEntity, User.class);
//Fetch Name
result.getName();
```

Of course, this is one of the methods to fetch result.You can also fetch the Response as String and then Map it to JSON to fetch the required data.

Answer (score 1):

restTemplate form submit the need to set the default HttpHeaders,
`

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
map.add("name", "yyyyyyy");
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String,String>>(map,headers);
```

`
 that request could get

```
`String name = request.getParameter("name");`
```